# arrayFormat equivalent in URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, query-string

Coming from `qs` we would control how arrays in query parameters would be with the `arrayFormat` option (quote from `qs` docs below):

> You may use the arrayFormat option to specify the format of the output array:
>
> ```
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'indices' })
> // 'a[0]=b&a[1]=c'
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' })
> // 'a[]=b&a[]=c'
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' })
> // 'a=b&a=c'
> qs.stringify({ a: ['b', 'c'] }, { arrayFormat: 'comma' })
> // 'a=b,c'
> ```

How can we control the format with `URLSearchParams`?

Doing:

```
new URLSearchParams({ a: ['b', 'c']})
```

Always gives `a=b,c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. That isn't a feature of `URLSearchParams`.

If you need that feature, then use `qs` instead.

Comment: Do you know if `urijs` lib supports it?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: There is a warning when installing `qs` via `npm`: `npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.` What should one use if `qs` API is considered legacy and the recommendation is to use `URLSearchParams` API instead but `URLSearchParams` does not have an equivalent to array format?